antd Trigger onChange event manually instead of waiting for clicks
I'm using antd RangePicker version 3.22.0. I've defined an onCalendarChange function that given a single choice, forces the other choice, thus negating the need for a second click.
Problem is, the component still requires a second click which is not the behavior I'm interested in.
Is there any way to bypass this two click mechanism? I thought that by forcing values it would work but it doesn't. Will triggering onChange manually help?
Heres the code:
        <DatePicker.RangePicker
            dropdownClassName={props.customParams && "custom-date-picker"}
            open={props.isOpen}
            value={props.markedDate}
            format={dateFormat}
            disabledDate={props.customParams?.disabledDates ?? TimeUtils.isDateAfterToday}
            showTime
            onOk={props.onOk}
            style={{opacity: 0}}
            separator={""}
            getCalendarContainer={props.calendarContainer}
            onCalendarChange={props.onCalendarChange}
            renderExtraFooter={props.renderExtraFooter}
            dateRender={renderDate}
        />

Thanks!
